# How to select specific items in list to make dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given

```
a = ['hello','world','1','2']
```

would like output (specifically for first element to make key from list)

dictionary or tuple

```
{'hello':['world','1','2']}
```

On second thought how would you generalize this to select any item to be key or value, values?

Answer (score 3):

You can use indexing and slicing

```
>>> a = ['hello','world','1','2']
>>> {a[0]: a[1:]}
{'hello': ['world', '1', '2']}
```

To pick any index as the key, and make all remaining items the values

```
def make_dict(items, index):
    return {items[index]: items[:index] + items[index+1:]}
```

For example

```
>>> a = ['hello','world','1','2']
>>> make_dict(a, 0)
{'hello': ['world', '1', '2']}
>>> make_dict(a, 1)
{'world': ['hello', '1', '2']}
>>> make_dict(a, 2)
{'1': ['hello', 'world', '2']}
>>> make_dict(a, 3)
{'2': ['hello', 'world', '1']}
```

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this down, this answers the OPs question. Voting up to balance.